# How to skip the blank cell value and pick up the next cell while Iterating an excel file using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an excel file where i have to read the header and the data Parallelly.I need a check ,while parsing the header if blank cell is found the i have to immediately skip the cell and pick up the next value but this can not be done in another iteration.Here i have tried but in my code i am getting no value in the skipped cell ,

```
       while (cellIterator.hasNext() && cellIteratorTotal.hasNext()) {

            cellCount++;
            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

            Cell currentCellTotal = cellIteratorTotal.next();

            currentRow =  sheet.getRow(currentRowTotal.getRowNum() + 1); // here i am trying to hold the current row value 

            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);

            String cellValueTotal = excelManager.evalCell(currentCellTotal);
            if(currentRow!=null) {
                String value = currentRow.getCell(currentCellTotal.getColumnIndex(), Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue(); //  here i am trying to get the next cell value 
            }
```

Can anyone help me with the correct approach please, Thanks in advance

Comment: in while loop first get the cell value if its empty increase the cell index by 1 then get cell value by that index and continue

Comment: @poojapatil can you edit my code please ?

Answer (score 1):

Below code can help you. Please check.
if (cell == null || c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {

}

Comment: and how to skip and pick up the value ?